# Folder recursion: when to return?

Tags: php, recursion, directory

What I am trying to do is recursively iterate through all the folders and gathering an $arr from each file that I will later merge.
In high level terms this is what I am doing:

```
function main(){
    $path = ....
    $arr = array();
    if(is_dir($path)){
       $arr = parseFolder($path, $arr);
    } else {
       $arr = parseFile($path);
    }
    print $arr;
}
function parseFile($path){
   ....
   return $arr
}

function parseFolder($path, $arr){
   $folder = opendir($path);
   while($item=readdir($folder)){
      if(is_dir($item)
          parseFolder($path . '/' . $item, $arr);
      else
          $arr = merge_array($arr, parseFile($path . '/' . $item);

   }
   return $arr
}
```

As you can see there is going to be a problem with this because I don't have a base case. So, it will eventually return $arr multiple times in the parseFolder function. Is there anyway to know when I'm virtually done iterating through all files/folders, so I know when to return my final result $arr? I'm open to more efficient implementations.

Comment: What is the ultimate aim? Do you just need all files in all folders, or associative nested arrays with the full folder structure?

Comment: I need all the files in the folders. The files return an array that I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace:

```
parseFolder($path . '/' . $item, $arr);
```

With

```
$arr = array_merge($arr, parseFolder($path . '/' . $item, $arr));
```

Otherwise all of your recursive calls will be thrown away.

Also, I don't think you have a full grasp on recursion as it seems that you think if you `return` at any point down deep in the recursion it will break all the way back out to the original call. This is incorrect.

The only caveats with recursive functions are:

1. Make sure you don't infinitely recurse, eg. in this case a symlink to a parent directory.
2. A sufficiently deep recursion can cause a stack overflow and crash your program.

For #1 you can simply avoid processing symlinks, or to cover both you can implement a depth limit. eg:

```
<?php
define('RECURSE_MAXDEPTH', 10);

function myRecurse($path, $depth=0) {
  $arr = array();
  $folder = opendir($path);
  while( $item = readdir($folder) ) {
    if( is_dir($item) ) {
      if( $depth < RECURSE_MAXDEPTH ) {
        $arr = array_merge($arr, myRecurse($path.'/'.$item, $depth+1));
      }
    } else {
      $arr = array_merge($arr, someFunction($item));
    }
  }
  return $arr;
}

$myArr = myRecurse('~sammitch/');
```

Comment: You are correct about me misunderstanding the recursion. Thank you for that. One thing though, I didn't need to do array_merge on the recurse. I just had to set $arr = parseFolder() otherwise I would have  duplicated values

Comment: As long as you take care of . and .. there isn't much use in limiting the depth and if you do you should throw an exception instead of silently return an inferior answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are some syntax errors in you code. Missing parenthesis several places, you used constant `folder` instead of variable `$folder` and I expect `merge_array` actually is `array_merge`?

Your solution seems to be a mix of two approaches:

Mutating version where the supplied reference is added to.

```
function parseFolder($path, &$arr)
{
    $folder = opendir($path);
    while($item=readdir($folder)) {
        // current and parent directory shouldn't be processed
        if( $item == '.' || $item == '..' )
            continue;
        elseif( is_dir($item) )
            parseFolder($path . '/' . $item, $arr);
        else
            $arr = array_merge($arr, parseFile($path . '/' . $item));
    }
    // the supplied array is updated with the result
}
```

A version that uses the return value of deeper recursion and build by value.

```
function parseFolder($path)
{
    $arr = array();
    $folder = opendir($path);
    while($item=readdir($folder)) {
        // current and parent directory shouldn't be processed
        if( $item == '.' || $item == '..' ) 
            continue;
        elseif( is_dir($item) )
            $arr = array_merge($arr, parseFolder($path . '/' . $item));
        else
            $arr = array_merge($arr, parseFile($path . '/' . $item));
    }
    return $arr;
}
```